# $H=\{x^2:x\in G\}$ then $H\unlhd G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

We have $H<G$ and element of $H$ is of the form $x^2$ where $x \in G$.

1. H is a normal subgroup of $G$.
2. The factor group $G/H$ is abelian.

I tried first one by showing that $gh^2g^{-1} \in H$. but I do not get any result from it. 
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first, $gh^2g^{-1}=ghg^{-1}ghg^{-1}$

Comment: and so… $gh^{2}g^{-1}=(ghg^{-1})^{2}$ how can I do not see this. I am blind. thanks

Comment: So if $x\in H$ then $x=h^2$ for some $h$ so $gxg^{-1}=g h^2g^{-1}=(g h g^{-1})^2$  is a square so  $gxg^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 3):

For the second, $(xH)^2=x^2H=H$ implies that in $G/H$ every element has order at most $2$ and so $G/H$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks. and the fact you used was new to me but I know how to do it that one.

Comment: A little more generally:In an associative monoid ( a set with an associative binary operation), if $a^2b=b=b a^2$ for all $a,b$ then $a b=b a$ for all $a,b$

Comment: @user254665 Is this a valid proof?${}$\begin{align}ab&=ab(ba)^2\\ &=abbaba\\&=a(b^2)aba\\&=(a^2)ba\\&=ba\end{align}

Comment: @ Akiva Weinberger. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $H=\{x^2 : x \in G \}$ is not necessarily a subgroup (counterexample $G=A_4$). Better put $H=\langle x^2 : x \in G \rangle$, so *generated* by squares.